# Sticky Footer with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, css, sticky-footer

I'm trying to get a background working with a sticky footer and I've hit a brick wall. For some reason, the blank space underneath `body` seems to stop at an elastic height above the bottom depending on the window height.

I can't see anything which could cause this and would really appreciate a pointer.

The demo site is at http://myfitzeek.lime49.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your [link](http://myfitzeek.lime49.com), you just change

```
   html {
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
   }

    #footer{
        position: absolute;
        ....
    }
```

to

```
    html {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
    }

    #footer {
        position: fixed;
        ....
    }
```

Comment: But that doesn't make the background behind repeat down like it should.

Comment: You have no idea how long I wrestled with this. For some reason people never seem to put a background on the `html` element. Thanks.